# Recruiter asking for re-interview in months

Tags: interviewing

Not sure what to make of the following situation. Here it is:

I interviewed at a major tech company for a software engineering position, level X. I was told that I passed the interview but didn't make level X, so they wanted to give me an offer for level X-1 instead. Additionally, the team I was interviewing for didn't have any level X-1 positions, so they needed to shop around to find a match for me at a different team.

I wasn't too thrilled about this so I was planning to only accept the offer if they managed to find me a good team. I think the recruiter sensed this. On my end, I also sensed that finding me another team was difficult for the recruiter as well.

A week later, I get an email asking if was I was okay with re-interviewing for the original position. I was told that I was really close to making level X, so the second interview would have a smaller loop (not sure what that means), and it would be in a few month (3 months later).

I'm a bit skeptical about this. I know major tech companies often have restrictions on how often a candidate can interview, but scheduling another interview 3 month out sounds like they want to keep me as a backup. I'm not sure if the position would be still available by then.

The question: Is this a trap?

Comment: I lose the level X-1 position.

Comment: I don't have a specific question. I'm asking for general input from the community because I haven't encounter something like this before. Maybe someone else can give insight that can help me decide. If you must have a question, then it would be something like "is this a trap?"

Comment: The restrictions for re-interview (every 12+ month) are generally for cases when you fail. Passing interview with offer for a lower level is definitely not a "failed interview" so I would not consider 3 month problematic from that point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just continue looking for a job. In the unlucky case that you don't find anything in three months, you go to their interview. But obviously you don't wait for them, and you don't give up another opportunity for them, especially not a better opportunity.

If you are the backup: If the person who got the job just didn't pass their three months probation, good for you. If they don't want you in three months, hopefully they will tell you before you go for an interview.